# Working place of 105 employees

Tags: combinatorics

A working place has 105 employees and 7 departments. If each employee works in 3 departments, and each department has the same number of employees how many employees work in each department?

I thought maybe the answer is $\frac{3*105}{7}$ ? I have no other idea how to approach it

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Answer (score 2):

If each employee works in 3 departments, the total number of employees across all department is $3 \times 105 = 315$. If each of the 7 departments has the same number of 150 employees, divide $315$ by $7$ to get your answer. (Yes, your solution was correct.)